# What does \\n means and how to remove it?

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a data set and should clean it. One example from my data:

```
new<-"\\nLocation:\\nMy home is conveniently located around the corner from the Galleria Mall. There's an abundance of food options in every direction of my place. There are also 2 movie theaters within 5 minute driving distance. Addison which is known for their restaurants and nightlife is a 5 minute drive.\\n-DFW  ; Lovefield Airport 20min\\n-American Airlines Center 15min\\n-Downtown 15min\\n-Deep Ellum, Lower Greenville, Uptown 20min"
```

I tried to use this function:

```
str_replace_all(new, "[\n]", "")
```

But it does not work.

**My questions:**

1. What difference between \n and \\n
2. How to remove it?

Comment: 1.) To understand the difference, compare `cat("\n")` with `cat("\\n")`. When these are passed to the regex engine, the same happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'\n'` is a new line character whereas `'\\n'` is an escaped backslash followed by `'n'`.

You can remove it by using `gsub` :

```
gsub('\\\\n', '', new)
```